# Find the Story Name In VersionOne using Project ID or Name python SDK

Tags: python, versionone

I am using the VersionOne Python SDK, and want to know the story names inside a certain project (Scope) i have the
project (Scope) id and name  , Using this project ID and name how to get the Story ID and Name?

v1 = V1Meta()

for scopeobj in v1.Scope.select('ID','Name').where(Name='Work Management'):
    print scopeobj.ID # this print the scpe ID

## But how to get the Story Names and ID, inside the project(Scope).

Answer (score 1):

you can use this approach:

The "filter" operator will take arbitrary V1 filter terms.

[Here's the Documentation about that:](https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.Python#advanced-query-taking-the-standard-v1-query-syntax)

`v1 = V1Meta()
for story in v1.Story.filter("Scope.ID='Scope:1122'"):
    print story
    print story.Name`